# Resources related to data-mining and gaming on social networks

Tags: social-networking, data-mining, social-gaming

I'm interested in the problem of patterning mining among players of social networking games.  For example detecting cheaters of a game, given a company's user database.  So far I have been following the usual recipe for a data mining project:

- construct a data warehouse that aggregates significant information
- select a classifier, and train it with a subsectio of records from the warehouse
- validate classifier with another test set
- lather, rinse, repeat

Surprisingly, I've found very little in this area regarding literature, best practices, etc.  I am hoping to crowdsource the information gathering problem here.  Specifically what I'm looking for:

- What classifiers have worked will for this type of pattern mining (it seems highly temporal, users playing games, users receiving rewards, users transferring prizes etc).
- Are there any highly agreed upon attributes specific to social networking / gaming data?
- What is a practical amount of information that should be considered? One problem I've run into is data overload, where queries and data cleansing may take days to complete.
- Related to point above, what hardware resources are required to produce results?  I've found it difficult to estimate the amount of computing power I will require for production use.  It has become apparent that a white box in the corner does not have enough horse-power for such a project.  Are companies generally resorting to cloud solutions?  Are they buying clusters?

Basically, any resources (theoretical, academic, or practical) about implementing a social networking / gaming pattern-mining program would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for the same kind of resources, here are some things I found that I consider pretty interesting, hope you can take advantage of it, please if you discover more resources let me know.
Here they are:
http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/06/turiya-media-games/
http://www.kdnuggets.com/2010/08/video-tutorial-christian-thurau-data-mining-in-games.html?k10n21
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2816/better_game_design_through_data_.php
This is in portuguesse but is excelent: http://thiagofalcao.info/